# sending email with smtp through php only working on remote server

Tags: php, email, sendmail, soap

I am trying to creat a little register/login page in php but I am stuck at sending the email to verify

I am using apache so I go to localHost/mypage.php

I am using JangoSMTP as an outgoing mail server and used their provide code [here](http://blog.jangomail.com/2010/11/technical-notes-using-jangomail-api.html)
I use it and tweek the code a bit then try it on my local server it works and I get the email

I then upload it via ftp to 000webhost

I try it and the email doesn't send

it gives me a fatel error

> Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /home/user/public_html/sendJango.php on line 6

I started this question on StackOverflow but they told me to go here so here I am?

please help

### thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our support team should be able to help you with this. You can contact us here: http://www.jangosmtp.com/Contact-Us.asp.